# Convert date to varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I convert a column which is `date` type to `varchar`?

Sample data:

```
ENDDATE (DATE TYPE)
'1947-12-01 00-00-00'
```

Requested results:

```
ENDDATE (VARCHAR)
    121947
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need the `ENDDATE` of value `'1947-12-01 00-00-00'` as `121947`. You can use the below query

```
SELECT RIGHT(MONTH(ENDDATE)*1010000+YEAR(ENDDATE),6)
```

Comment: This will return int, you should wrap it with a cast to char(6).

Comment: Thanx @ZoharPeled, modified the answer.

Comment: One more thing - for mothes before October this will return a 5 digit result. The OP didn't specify if that's good or bad. Easy to fix if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with 2012 version or higher, you can use format. For earlier versions you can use convert with some string manipulations:

```
DECLARE @D as date = '1947-12-01'

SELECT  REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(10), @d, 103), 7), '/', '') As charValue2008,
        FORMAT(@d, 'MMyyyy') as charValue2012
```

Results:

```
charValue2008   charValue2012
121947          121947
```

Please note that `Format` runs relativley slow, so if you have a lot of rows you might want to choose another way to do that.